# Utilizing colors from firebase remote config in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I'm a little confused with this, and the examples I've dug up only seem to indicate simple things.. like changing the color of the tool bar.

So for instance, I'm trying to change the text color of a clustered map marker created by the android map utils IconGenerator class.  The text can be styled by using `mClusterIconGenerator.setTextAppearance(R.style.ClusterStyle)` and this style defines textColor.

This is a broader question than just that example - how can I go about applying colors all over the app based on ones parsed from remote config?  I've created some data binding methods and started updating each text view, or button, one by one in XML to set its color via a binding method as styles reference color resources, which firebase cannot overwrite.

Thanks for any leads, and if I'm trying to use remote config for far more than it was intended than lemme know!

Answer (score 0):

My personal opinion on that is getting specific UI values for each component one by one from Firebase remote config is definitely far more than its purpose. However, what you can do with remote config is let's say you have multiple theme options for your app like "day mode" and "night mode" which are already built-in your app. You can switch between and apply one of these themes by checking a remote property in Firebase remote config.